# EF intercepting calls when running queries using Dapper library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dapper

I have an issue where part of a system is using Entity Framework, while another library is using Dapper to run some existing database work.

When making calls from dapper the EF intercepts the calls from Dapper and the dapper calls fail.

I think this is because in the EF library someone has implemented an IDbCommandInterceptor and it is somehow also intercepting the normal database connections used in Dapper.

Would anyone know of a way to get the EF to ignore the connections that are being used by Dapper, to leave them out of it's interception.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. `IDbCommandInterceptor` is EF specific interface, so EF cannot intercept other ADO.NET calls. Except if *your* system  is passing EF DbConnection to Dapper, in which cases there is nothing you can do - you have to fix your system.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, but the Dapper library is creating its own connections it is not using the EF ones. We can see the connection after it is opened in Dapper and it is pointing to the correct DB. When we execute a query we suddenly jump into a EF DBContext class and nothing works after that.

Comment: What is the actual type of the `DbConnection` object used by Dapper? When you say `cn.GetType()`? Also I'm pretty sure Dapper does not create connections, it provides extension methods for connections passed by the users of that library.

Comment: It's a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection that is used.@Ivan.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but that's not possible, I mean EF cannot intercept ADO.NET connections/commands, only its own.

Comment: This clearly requires an [mcve]. We can only guess how your `IDbCommandInterceptor` implementation and connections used by Dapper can interfere. Maybe you use EF to generate SQL strings?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason this was happening was because the ASP.NETZero framework was implementing a UnitOfWork pattern which was intercepting the calls.

Thanks to everyone for the replies, sorry for the late update, work seems to get in the way of everything these days.

Kind Regards